# 3 Volt Active Low Relay

Tags: arduino, relay

I got this Relay: [Link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1Pcs-1-Channel-3V-Relay-Module-with-Lights-without-Optocoupler-Blackboard/32811523122.html)

It's a 3V 3.3V Relay "Active LOW" and I want to use it with an Arduino Micro. So far I only had experiences with Box/Printrelais.

I want to power the relay via the 3V Pin of the Arduino and toggle between NC and NO via Pin 12.

I tried it and and worked. Setting Pin 12 to LOW activates the Relay on the NC position.

I am not sure however if this setup is safe for the Arduino and the relay? I think setting Pin 12 from LOW to HIGH puts out more then 3 Volts.

Does the 3V 3.3V Relay description only refer to the coil voltage and is it ok to toggle it via a Digital Out pin without additional resistors?

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245976/control-5v-relay-through-3-3v-gpio-using-npn-transistor/246003#246003.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't just got a relay. You have a relay module.

[image]

*Figure 1. Relay module with switching transistor highlighted.*

The transistor highlighted in the image is what switches the relatively high relay coil current by the relatively small control signal on the IN pin.

> Does the 3V 3.3V Relay description only refer to the coil voltage and is it ok to toggle it via a Digital Out pin without additional resistors?

The Vcc pin should be powered from 3.3 V. The input should be driven by a 3.3 V logic signal. It may tolerate a 5 V logic signal but without a datasheet we can't say for sure.

---

See Michael Karas' answer to [Control 5v relay through 3.3v GPIO using NPN transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245976/control-5v-relay-through-3-3v-gpio-using-npn-transistor/246003#246003) where he has drawn the likely schematics.

Comment: Yes, the lack of a datasheet for the overall module is problematic.  I wouldn't have bought it myself, for that reason alone.

Comment: yeah... probably a very good point for future projects :-)

Answer (score -2):

It's a solid-state relay, so there is in fact no "coil" and the current drawn from the Arduino is likely quite small.  I suggest using an ammeter to measure it.

A good thing it *is* a solid-state device, as your experiment would probably have fried your Arduino with a conventional relay.  Induction coils are nasty things to connect directly to CMOS logic.

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast reply but I'm not quite sure what to do now. I measured the Output when setting Pin 12 to HIGH and I got 5V so I'm assuming that the 3 Volt relay is better used with an ESP8266 or something similar that runs on 3 -3.3 Volt. My question is what does the 3 V 3.3 on the relay actually refer to.

Comment: That is **not solid state**. Just look at the thing. *Clearly* a standard relay. Also here is the a datasheet for an eqivalent relay (based on the JQC model number): https://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/JQC-3F(T73).pdf

Comment: Hmm, looks like the item description was inaccurate in that case (it clearly says "solid state relay").  According to another answer, it is indeed a conventional relay, but in a module which safely encapsulates the coil in a way that's safe for low-power 3V or 3.3V logic to drive.  Which leaves open the question of whether it's 5V tolerant...