# Switch on a 10 A circuit with only a 20 mA signal

Tags: relay, 12v

I'm attempting to wire in a 12 V fan to my car that draws 7 A at full speed.  The fan is a fused link directly to the battery.  I have a 12 V 20 mA signal wire, but that doesn't appear to be strong enough to trigger a standard automotive relay RL44.
[image]

Are there any options to support such a high switching current from such a low signal current?

---

@Winny and @Spephro Pefhany suggested a pilot/bootstrap.  Is this the idea of how that would work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe3hzR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Bootstrap yourself with a transistor, preferably MOSFET to pull the relay?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the bootstrap concept?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control 5v relay through 3.3v GPIO using NPN transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245976/control-5v-relay-through-3-3v-gpio-using-npn-transistor)

Comment: Follow the link above and replace your bottom relay with a MOSFET.

Comment: Thank you.  I had read through the link but it hadn't felt applicable due to the lower voltage and use of resistors.  I'm certainly still a novice in this realm.  I assume heat wont be a factor since the RL44 will only draw 140 mA?

Comment: Choose a MOSFET with low enough RdsON to not cause excessive heating by P=0.14^2*RdsON. Don’t forget a flyback diode across your relay coil. Or just use a BJT and resistor as in this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVgTy.png

Comment: @Bill, when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar you can save an editable version of your schematic in your question. No account needed and no need for screengrabs with the grid showing. We can also copy your schematic and edit it in our answers.

Comment: Thanks winny.  I have a couple IRFBE30 mosfets already on a heatsink that i salvaged from something.  Likewise a couple GP10B diodes from something else. They look like they'll work, but i only have a rudimentary understanding of datasheets.  I've updated the schematic above.

Comment: You need a pulldown resistor on the input, and some ESD protection as FET gates are quite sensitive to ESD.

Comment: @Transistor Awesome, thank you!  Coincidentally, i had been using CircuitLab's website to make the screenshot.  Amazingly, it let me copy from that other browser instance and paste into the stackExchange instance.

Comment: No, your drawing is upside down. IRFBE30 is an N channel. Connect it as shown in the schematic link I gave you.

Comment: I'd start with making sure you know how your "signal" works. The fan control failed in my friend's car recently. Turns out it is PWM signal (active low) that comes into fan control module. The module is basically transistor switch, so he replaced it with mosfet

Answer (score 4):

You could use a small pilot relay or a transistor to switch the automotive relay.

An example of such as relay would be the [G5Q-1A4 DC12](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5q.pdf)  from Omron, about 1.50 USD each. It takes 16.7mA coil current.

It's rated at 10A current so it may be able to switch the fan directly, but the automotive relay may last longer particularly if you don't put a diode across the fan. DC rating is 10A carry and 5A switched, so it's marginal and the initial surge may cause the contacts to weld so probably not a good idea.

An RL44 is rated at 40A (resistive load) and the coil draws 140mA.

---

Edit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxRklA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It looks like that G5Q-1A4 supports 10 A for AC, but is only 5 A DC.  Good find on the RL44 coil draw... i've been searching and couldn't find it.

Comment: This is true, rated to carry but not switch 10A. Another reason to use the automotive relay to switch the fan itself is that it will be  more resistant to welding from the initial surge with the motor stalled.

Comment: Thank you.  I modified my question to have an image. Do you mind checking it to see if I have the right idea as to what you're proposing?

Comment: Not enough information- is the "signal" active high or low? Is it open when off or actively pulled in each direction? There is enough information to say your schematic is wrong and will blow up (diode is the wrong way and the MOSFET is the wrong type). Also MOSFET gates  need some protection in an automotive environment. I didn't suggest the MOSFET, because I thought it would get complicated compared to just a relay. @Winny can answer that if he wants.
Added schematic for pilot relay with coil diode, assuming active high. If that's wrong you can flip it or use the NC contact.

Comment: A 1N400x (eg. 1N4005) can be put across the RL44 coil too (same direction as the pilot relay).

Comment: Thank you.  My experience is minimal, so i appreciate simplicity.